# figure of imshow() is too small

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize a numpy array using imshow() since it's similar to imagesc() in Matlab.

```
imshow(random.rand(8, 90), interpolation='nearest')
```

The resulting figure is very small at the center of the grey window, while most of the space is unoccupied. How can I set the parameters to make the figure larger? I tried figsize=(xx,xx) and it's not what I want. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just adding this comment in case others like me struggle to land on this post --- the problem happens (most visibly) when the x and y data are of different orders of magnitude; @bmu's answer fixes it

Answer (score 207, accepted):

If you don't give an `aspect` argument to `imshow`, it will use the value for `image.aspect` in your `matplotlibrc`. The default for this value in a new `matplotlibrc` is `equal`.
So `imshow` will plot your array with equal aspect ratio.

If you don't need an equal aspect you can set `aspect` to `auto`

```
imshow(random.rand(8, 90), interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
```

which gives the following figure

[image: imshow-auto]

If you want an equal aspect ratio you have to adapt your `figsize` according to the aspect

```
fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(18, 2))
ax.imshow(random.rand(8, 90), interpolation='nearest')
tight_layout()
```

which gives you:

[image: imshow-equal]

Comment: besides defining the aspect ratio, is it possible to get(define) the size of the colored tiles?

Answer (score 86):

That's strange, it definitely works for me:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize = (20,2))
plt.imshow(random.rand(8, 90), interpolation='nearest')
```

I am using the "MacOSX" backend, btw.

Comment: to be clear, it must be  `plt.figure(figsize = (x_new, y_new))` and for imgshow()  you must now import ioimage because the SciPy imageshow() will be deprecated soon

Comment: @AgileBean it would be useful if you were to either edit this post with that information or add it as an answer to this question

Answer (score 11):

### Update 2020

#### as requested by @baxxx, here is an update because `random.rand` is deprecated meanwhile.

This works with matplotlip 3.2.1:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

random = np.random.random ([8,90])

plt.figure(figsize = (20,2))
plt.imshow(random, interpolation='nearest')
```

This plots:

[image]

To change the random number, you can experiment with `np.random.normal(0,1,(8,90))` (here mean = 0, standard deviation = 1).

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to python too. Here is something that looks like will do what you want to

```
axes([0.08, 0.08, 0.94-0.08, 0.94-0.08]) #[left, bottom, width, height]
axis('scaled')`
```

I believe this decides the size of the canvas.