# Matplotlib imshow() stretch to "fit width"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got an image, and a measure associated with each column of its pixels. I'm using `pyplot` to create a figure with the image on top, and a plot of the column measurements below. I'm using something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.rand(34*52).reshape(34,52)
means = np.average(A,axis=0)

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.imshow(A, interpolation='nearest' )

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(means)

plt.show()
```

How can I stretch the image's width to the match that of the plots. That way, when looking at the measurements in the plot, the souce pixels will be in a column directly above it.

Comment: for matlab questions better use http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yet another stack exchange site I didn't know about! I wish my one login worked for them all... can this be migrated, or should I repost?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think you should repost this.

Comment: I reposted at stats, but someone migrated it over here almost immediately! I voted to delete and will just go with this!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10540929/1301710

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Turns out that it's as simple as giving `aspect='auto'` to the `imshow` call.

```
plt.imshow(A, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
```