# How to enlarge image axis in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a heatmap of two variables. The problem part of the code looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.99, 0.98, 0.99, 1, 1]
y = [1, 1, 0.5, 0.8, 1]

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent, origin="lower")
plt.show()
```

Here I've used just the first few lines of the data that I want to plot. One of the two variables is very clustered around 0.95-1, while the other runs much more freely (it can even go into the hundreds of thousands). The problem is that the output looks like the figure below.

[image]

I'd like to widen the x-axis so I can see the area being plotted in more detail. I've tried using the `axis()` command, but it just adds white space (i.e. space with no data). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This was a well-worded question, but we usually leave off things like "thanks" or "please". It's understood as part of the question (and we like to remove unnecessary text). Remember to upvote good answers (when you get enough rep) and accept answers to your questions!

Comment: My apologies. I'll be sure to upvote your answer when I can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be using `extent` note that

```
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
```

gives `extent=[0.99,1,1,1]`. You should change it to something like:

```
extent = [min(xedges), max(xedges), min(yedges), max(yedges)]
```

You may also find `plt.axis("equal")` to be useful. [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) will also interpolate by default, which is usually not what you want. The argument `interpolation="none"` stops this. This related question may address more of your issues:

[figure of imshow() is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540929/figure-of-imshow-is-too-small)

Comment: Thanks, the aspect = "auto" command suggested in the related question fixed the issue. I have a question though. What's the difference between the two ways of defining extent? I tried using both ways of defining it and there doesn't appear to be a difference. Thanks!

Comment: In python, if you have a list `A=[2,7,1,4]`, then `A[0]=2`, `A[-1]=4`, e.g. the -1 indexes the _last_ element of the list. The extent should take in the bounds that you want to plot, i.e. the minimum and maximum of the list! In this case the extent might not be the problem, but I wanted to note that it wasn't doing what you expected.