# Matplotlib imshow() collapsing for axes values of different orders of magnitude

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heatmap using imshow(). When my x and y data values are all of similar order of magnitude, it works fine. However, if x and y are different orders of magnitude (for example, all 0 < x < 1.0 and all y > 1.0), it collapses the plot along the axis with small numbers, as below. How do I avoid this?

[image: plot]

Comment: I encourage you to read the FAQ on using stackoverflow, to prevent some of the people on the site from downvoting your stuff without leaving comments as to why.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was trying to keep the question concise, as I knew my specific code didn't pertain to the issue at hand (it was stemming from a default attribute I was unaware of)

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled on this question (wasn't finding it before because of my phrasing/keyword differences), which has the answer I'm looking for.

[figure of imshow() is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540929/figure-of-imshow-is-too-small)

I'll leave my question here as a pointer in case anyone else uses my search terms.

What's happening (explained on the link) is that imshow defaults to having its `aspect` parameter default to `"equal"`, which causes the behavior described in my initial question. To fix this, set `aspect="auto"`. For example:

```
ax.imshow(data, aspect="auto", **kwargs)
```

Comment: What specifically was the problem? You should explicitly state what the solution is here, in case something happens to the link

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity; edited. Will mark as solution once the minimum time has passed

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [specify the size of the figure, using figsize](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html).

Figsize accepts a tuple with two floats: (width, height)

To use it with `imshow()`:

```
fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(18, 2))
ax.imshow(random.rand(8, 90), interpolation='nearest')
tight_layout()
```

Or if you just want to use pyplot.plot() you could try something like:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
```

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html

Comment: I've already been setting the figsize in my code; that hasn't remedied the issue for imshow, however

Comment: Can you show us a code snippet / bare bones of what you did? You didn't specify what you tried in your question.

Comment: I just used `ax.imshow(data, **kwargs)` --- in my case, I was only setting `extent`, `origin`, and `cmap` (none of which are relevant to the problem described, which was only a function of the input data disparity in magnitude, as explained)

Comment: I suppose that the purpose of this answer is essentially the same as marking the question as duplicate of the linked one... which I just did.