# WordCloud size not increasing despite a big Mask

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sizeof, wordcloud2

I have been trying this since morning and breaking my head... nothing seems to increase the size of the output in Jupyter notes. Despite the mask being as big as 2100*1980. Please tell me where am going wrong

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from wordcloud import WordCloud
mask = np.array(Image.open('pentagon.jpg'))
wc = WordCloud(mask=mask, scale=5, background_color='white',collocations=False,
           max_words=500, max_font_size=256)
wc.generate_from_frequencies(k)
wc.prefer_horizontal=0.7
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

and the output is here...so small. I even tried plt.figure and stuff but nothing is working in increasing the size of the output. Please suggest where am going wrong
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540929/figure-of-imshow-is-too-small) answer your question

Comment: NO LUCK, tried both interpolation='nearest' and aspect = 'auto'. Image output size is same...