# Increase the display size of image in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a set of images on my system, which I am loading into my Jupyter notebook and then trying to display them all together using matplotlib.

The code is as follows:

```
for i,k in enumerate(image_list):
    fig = plt.figure("Results: %s" % (methodName))
    fig.suptitle("Correlation", fontsize = 10)

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, len(image_list), i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[k])
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,9]
    plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

Here ***image_list*** is a list containing image names, while ***images*** is a dictionary which contains image name as key and image as value.

When I display the 20 images together, the displayed images are very small in size and I am not able to increase the height or width of the image.

I tried the `figsize` in `plt.figure` as well as in `plt.rcParams` but both do not work.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you could change the figure size before running the loop with `plt.figure(figsize = (64,45))` , for example

Comment: I believe the problem could be with `imshow`. Does this answer your question? [figure of imshow() is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540929/figure-of-imshow-is-too-small)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `figure(figsize=(1,1))` would creat an inch-by-inch image

> Here is a small example

```py
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure(num=None,figsize=(100,100),dpi=80,facecolor='w',edgecolor='k')
a=[1,5,7,9]
b=[4,6,8,7]
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

`dpi=80` will show `figure` of 80 pixel

> OUTPUT
> [image]