# How to read .png file with matplotlib to not lack information?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, imshow

I have created a png file with matplotlib. When opened in a Viewer it shows all the parts of the graph.
However, when reading the image with matplotlib, only the coordinate system is shown, not the bars.

I created the plot using spectrum_utils.

```
import spectrum_utils.plot as sup
import spectrum_utils.spectrum as sus

import matplotlib as plt

db_hit_spectrum = sus.MsmsSpectrum('9407', 200.2373, 1, [71.0852, 85.1012], [2, 1])
query_spectrum = sus.MsmsSpectrum('9407', 200.2372, 1, [71.0858, 85.1013, 98.9841], [13000000., 6700000., 850000.])

fig, ax_1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax_1.set_title(f"DB hit of N-Methyldodecylamine and query spectrum with ID 9407")
sup.mirror(query_spectrum, db_hit_spectrum, spectrum_kws={'grid': False})

fig.savefig("test.png")

a = plt.imread("test.png")
plt.imshow(a)
```

The picture this saves:

[image: The picture I save]

The picture shown after reading it back in:

[image: The picture shown after reading]

Also, when calling the spectrum_utils functions, I can get back the peaks, but I want to read the picture somewhere I do not have the information necessary.

**Edit:**

The picture after using `plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('test.png'), aspect='auto')`:

[image: The picture after using aspect='auto']

When reading it back in, I now have the problem of a a picture in a picture.

Comment: `plt.imshow(a, aspect='auto')`? As per [figure of imshow() is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10546220/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you, it helped. Not sure how to describe the new problem

Comment: Maybe you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734723/7758804 instead.

Comment: Otherwise remove all spines with `ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)` and remove x/y ticks and  ticklabels with `ax.set_xticks([])` and `ax.set_yticks([])`. Where you plotted on an axes with `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))` and `ax.imshow(a, aspect='auto')`

Comment: `pickle.dump(fig, open('myplot.pickle', 'wb'))` and `ax = pickle.load(open('myplot.pickle', mode='rb'))` with `import pickle`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks again. Pickle is probably what will help me. However, I get Error: _Can't pickle local object 'mirror.<locals>.<lambda>'_, but I'm not using lambda.
[same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict), I dont understand the problem really

Comment: I tested this pickle code on a file and it worked without issue. You might try making sure your packages are up-to-date python, matplotlib, etc. if you were using anaconda, the easiest way is to go to the Anaconda prompt and do `conda update --all`